# Select data to comply with a condition that relate to another table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

## Help

Considering that a passenger lives in his first flight departure town, find those passengers among dwellers of other cities who visited Moscow more than once. Result set: passenger´s name, number of visits to Moscow.

[image: Details]

Im trying to solve this query but i dont know how to take the city from departure and then take this to select which people flying the most to moscow, please Help.

```
select p.name, count(pt.trip_no) from passenger as p, trip as t, pass_in_trip as pt
where pt.trip_no = t.trip_no and town_to='Moscow'
group by pt.trip_no;
```

my result set is this

```
'Bruce Willis', '128'
'Bruce Willis', '64'
```

but i dont know how to get people that flying more than once time to moscow

Comment: We are NOT here to do your homework or your tests for you. You need to learn how to do this on your own. Good luck!!!

Comment: This is either homework or a test.

Comment: Is it MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Can you explain your attempts. what you have tried, or any error?

Comment: Srry i forget to add my own query im lost in this query, may u can help me with ideas :D please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure why they're teaching comma separated joins but you can do this

```
SELECT  p.id_psg,
        p.name,
        COUNT(pt.trip_no)
FROM    passenger AS p
        INNER JOIN pass_in_trip pit ON p.id_psg = pit.id_psg
        INNER JOIN trip AS t ON pit.trip_no = t.trip_no
WHERE   t.town_to = 'Moscow'
GROUP BY p.id_psg,
        p.NAME
HAVING  COUNT(pt.trip_no) > 1;
```

your biggest problem is that you were not joining passenger to pass_in_trip correctly because you didnt list the join condition in your where.. INNER JOIN will help prevent this.

Since the text also clearly states passengers can have the same name, you should also include ID_psg in your group by since that is the unique identifier.

Comment: im trying but the problem is if one person go to moscow in the table trip doesnt contains info about the person, and the pass_in_trip cointains the info of the person

Comment: forget that i saw this is the correct answe thank you a lot i used a twice of times inner join but i never understand how it works